# Ajax request to php file with no response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

I have the code below requesting a php file result:

```
var fn_name  = function(data){
    var tmp = 'no change';
    $.ajax({
        type:       'POST'
        , url:      'std/files/fn/cquery.php'
        , cache:    false
        , data:     { query:data }
        , success:  function(data){ tmp = data; }
        , error:    function()    { tmp = 'error'; }
    });
    return tmp;
}
```

And here is the php file:

```
<?php
function cquery($data){
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost','user','pswd','db');
    if(($conn->query($data))->fetch_assoc()){
        return 'true';
    }else{
        return 'false';
    }
}
if(isset($_POST['query'])){ echo cquery($_POST['query']); }
?>
```

The problem is that the fn_name('correct query here') returns 'no change'. The Ajax's success is been executed, inserting an alert() there works...

Can't figure out what's happening...

Comment: try setting `async : false`. Since the ajax call is in async mode, the ajax call will not wait  for success response, so you get **'no change'** as result.

Comment: Also, this is a terrible terrible idea. You should not be accepting user provided data as it, let alone full queries.

Comment: The problem that @Haridarshan decribes is almost certainly the / a problem going by the code you've given.

Comment: @Haridarshan, thanks... it worked...